# What is the difference between built-in (or embedded) languages in FreeSWITCH and scripts using the Event Socket Library (ESL)?

Tags: freeswitch

Many languages are embedded into FreeSWITCH (such as JavaScript, see [the docs](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/JavaScript)), made possible by [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) "[*to make the core FreeSWITCH library accessible to scripting*](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781785889134/8/ch08lvl1sec48/many-scripting-languages?query=swig)".

Languages can also use the [Event Socket Library](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1048914) for the same purpose, so what is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the FreeSWITCH 1.2 book points out](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781782161004/9/ch09lvl1sec81/using-esl-to-execute-commands), they are indeed not the same:

> #### ESL scripts versus built-in languages
>
> Keep in mind that ESL-based programs are not the same as using
>   built-in languages. The FreeSWITCH event socket is a TCP-based
>   connection to FreeSWITCH. The ESL is an abstraction library that is
>   available for more languages than just the few that are built-in to
>   FreeSWITCH. You must first install the Lua, Perl, Python, or PHP for
>   your system before using ESL.

**Built-in languages** ship with a FreeSWITCH installation by default, and they can be used to write scripts to control (and configure<sup>1</sup>) a FreeSWITCH instance instead of editing the XML files to achieve the same. These scripts can only be called either from a [dialplan action](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/XML+Dialplan#XMLDialplan-The10,000FootView) or form the console as an API call (e.g., look for [`luarun`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_lua) or [`jsrun`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/JavaScript)).

**Scripts using the [Event Socket Library (ESL)](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1048914)** can be run from anywhere achieving the same results as built-in languages, but first they establish a network connection to the FreeSWITCH instance to be able to send API calls.

---

1 See [Serving Configuration with `mod_lua`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Serving+Configuration+with+Lua) and [Serving Configuration with JavaScript](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Serving+Configuration+with+JavaScript) documentation pages.

Comment: `(and configure?)` - yes. There is an article on confluence called "Serving Configuration with mod_lua" (https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Serving+Configuration+with+Lua ). You can do it using javascript via mod_v8 as well https://freeswitch.org/jira/browse/FS-9896

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer. I completely missed the Lua config subpage for somehow.